# Install hadoopy in google composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, hadoopy

I am using `google composer`.

How can we install **hadoopy** in `google composer environment`.

This page has steps for [installing](https://hadoopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#installing-hadoopy) hadoopy in Linux machine

**Github Clone**

```
git clone https://github.com/bwhite/hadoopy.git
cd hadoopy
sudo python setup.py install
```

**PIP installation**

```
sudo pip install -e git+https://github.com/bwhite/hadoopy#egg=hadoopy
```

I am not getting how to install this in Google Composer Environment

Answer (score 3):

The package seems to be available on [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/project/hadoopy/0.6.0/). So you can install it via the web UI (your composer environment > Pypi packages tab > edit > add `<your_dependency>==<version>`). You can also do that via command-line :

```sh
gcloud composer environments update ENVIRONMENT-NAME \
    --update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt \
    --location LOCATION
```

`requirements.txt` should then contain something like :

```
hadoopy==0.6.0
```

Note that installing the dependency can be quite long (Composer needs to rebuild Docker images with the included package).

If you want to add the dependency directly from sources on Github, you'll have to  follow the steps described in the docs : [Installing a local Python library](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-local).